# When there are multiple boot devices, they are not booted in the order defined in BOOT_ORDER?

Tags: pi-4, bootloader, pi4-eeprom

I have a pi4. Today, I want to set up USB booting. After I executed the following procedure, I found that the USB booting was successful, but when I plug both the SD boot device and the USB boot device into the Raspberry Pi4B, it should boot from the SD card device, but it actually boots from the USB boot device.

The following code is my operation process：

```
jiamingpi@jiamingpi-desktop:~$ sudo vcgencmd bootloader_config > bootconf.txt
jiamingpi@jiamingpi-desktop:~$ cat bootconf.txt
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
BOOT_ORDER=0xf41 # this is new added parameter when I first gedit bootloader_config

jiamingpi@jiamingpi-desktop:~$ rpi-eeprom-config --out pieeprom-new.bin --config bootconf.txt /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical/pieeprom-2020-09-03.bin

jiamingpi@jiamingpi-desktop:~$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -f ./pieeprom-new.bin

jiamingpi@jiamingpi-desktop:~$ sudo reboot
```

This is eeprom's info, may help you solve my question:

```
jiamingpi@jiamingpi-desktop:~$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update
BCM2711 detected
Dedicated VL805 EEPROM detected
BOOTLOADER: up-to-date
CURRENT: 2020年 09月 03日 星期四 12:11:43 UTC (1599135103)
 LATEST: 2020年 09月 03日 星期四 12:11:43 UTC (1599135103)
 FW DIR: /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical
VL805: up-to-date
CURRENT: 000138a1
 LATEST: 000138a1
```

Comment: `BOOT_ORDER=0xf41` is the default order anyway, so you've achieved no change - but, you're right, it should boot from SD ... if you remove USB does it boot from SD?

Comment: try switching to stable branch - maybe that works?

Comment: Also try to use `rpi-eeprom-config` for viewing / editing the config. Recent raspi-config also has options to modify boot order (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md)

Comment: @JaromandaX When I unplug the USB device and only use the SD card to start, it can start normally. Similarly, when I only use the USB device, it can also start normally.

Comment: I assume the SD card and USB drive have different PARTUUID's?

Answer (score 1):

guys, thanks a lot for focusing on this question. I think I may find the reason why it doesn't work.

In a short, my Raspberry OS maybe not correct. Reference to the link [ubuntu-mage](https://ubuntu-mate.org/ports/raspberry-pi/), title **Additional features** about USB booting, shows **Ubuntu MATE 20.10 and newer support USB booting, but Ubuntu MATE 20.04 does not.** So when I installed Ubuntu MATE 20.10 on SD card, it worked, which means OS will start from SD card when SD card and USB system device both plunged.

thx.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved this! Please select your answer as the correct one (or another answer if you prefer) by "clicking" the check mark icon in the margin beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it will do you much good to hear an "it works here" but it does. I just booted my Pi 4 with a 64bit version of the Pi OS Buster to get the vcgencmd command installed on my new pure Debian buster install, I thought it would work since they are based on the same OS and it did. I wrote up the procedure on here. When booting the Card I never disconnected the SSD and it just booted into the card as it is supposed to being hardwired with that a first in the order even after changing to USB boot, that is how you do a chainload boot using the /boot on the card and a / file system on the SSD.

Here are my settings for the boot loader using my fancy new command I installed.

```
root@buster-raspi:~# vcgencmd bootloader_config
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
DHCP_TIMEOUT=45000
DHCP_REQ_TIMEOUT=4000
TFTP_FILE_TIMEOUT=30000
TFTP_IP=
TFTP_PREFIX=0
BOOT_ORDER=0xf41
[none]
FREEZE_VERSION=0

root@buster-raspi:~# vcgencmd bootloader_version
Dec 11 2020 11:15:17
version c3f26b6070054bca030366de2550d79ddae1207a (release)
timestamp 1607685317
```

It runs great with the pure Debian on it.

```
root@buster-raspi:~# cat /etc/debian_version 
10.8
root@buster-raspi:~# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
root@buster-raspi:~# uname -a
Linux buster-raspi 5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1~bpo10+1 (2020-12-31) aarch64 GNU/Linux
```